# What is socle friendly group means?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, socle

In the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4122) by Ben Elias et al. (2010), the authors has defined the socle friendly group.

Definition 1: Let $G$ be an arbitrary finite group, and let $\mathcal{T}=\{T \triangleleft G \,|\, T \leq \mathrm{Soc}(G) \} $. We call $G$ socle friendly if for all $H < G, T \in \mathcal{T}$, we have $\mathrm{RC}_G(H \cdot T) = \mathrm{RC}_G(H) \cdot T$, where $\mathrm{RC}_G(H)= \mathrm{Core}_G(H) \cap \mathrm{Soc}(G)$. Here [$\mathrm{Core}_G(H)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_(group_theory)#:%7E:text=The%20normal%20core-,Definition,of%20H%20under%20S%2C%20i.e.) is the largest normal subgroup in $G$ containing in $H$.

I understand what is $\mathrm{RC}_G(H)$. Informally saying, it is a subgroup generated by those minimal normal subgroups which are in $\mathrm{Core}_G(H)$

Can someone explain definition 1 and the notation $H \cdot T$ ?

Comment: I think $H \cdot T$ just means $HT$. We always have ${\rm RC}_G(T)T \le {\rm RC}_G(HT)$, and the definition just says that we don't get anything extra in the core, apart from $T$ itself, when we adjoin $T$ to the subgroup $H$.  There is an example showing that this condition does not always hold.